# Autohotkey multiple hotkeys mapping to the same function

Tags: autohotkey

I have several hotkeys that all do the same things, I have multiples so I can call them wherever my hands happen to be at the time and can be used on multiple keyboards eg:

```
#]::Send {Media_Next}
XButton2 & RButton::Send {Media_Next}
SC15D & ]::Send {Media_Next}
```

Is there any way to combine these things onto one line without having to repeat myself all over the place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple hotkey definitions in one line can't be done, at least not without a genuine hack.
Still, there are ways to simplify your script:

### Method 1: "Trickling hotkeys"

This is the simplest and most straight-forward way to assign multiple hotkeys the same functionality. It works by simply writing the hotkeys one below the other, only assigning the last hotkey one or several commands:

```
#]::
XButton2 & RButton::
SC15D & ]::Send {Media_Next}
```

### Method 2: Dynamic hotkey creation

Using the `Hotkey` command, you can assign labels to hotkeys at runtime. This means, they can be used in a loop:

```
for i, keyName in ["#]", "XButton2 & RButton", "SC15D & ]"]
    Hotkey, % keyName, SendMediaNext

Exit

SendMediaNext: 
    Send {Media_Next}
return
```

Hotkeys created at runtime aren't as performant as hard-coded hotkeys, but in most cases, you won't notice a difference. I would still go with Method 1, since it's more readable.