# Is it possible to use two keys , either one to execute a function in AutoHotKey (AHK) script

Tags: autohotkey

i am trying a script for a game , click "E" or Shift+E (shift -> while running). How do i use "OR" in AHK ?

```
e OR +e::
{
Send, E
Sleep, 50
Send, E
Sleep, 50
Send, F
}
return
```

Comment: i idea is that i click E to execute something OR i can even use SHIFT+E for the same execution

Answer (score 1):

```
$e:: 
$+e:: 
Send, E 
Sleep, 50 
Send, E 
Sleep, 50 
Send, F  
return
```

The `$` prevents the `Send, E` to trigger the hotkey again.

Also check this link [Autohotkey multiple hotkeys mapping to the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21849607/11064295)

Comment: This doesnt work , anyways thank you for the comment

Comment: @MuhammadAzhar Additionally, if you want to have a 50ms delay between sending keys, you could use `SetKeyDelay , 50` and `SendEvent , EEF` to achieve the same thing as you have with the 3x `Send` and 2x `Sleep`. (Note: `SendInput` doesn't obey `SetKeyDelay`.)

Comment:  it works when i add the “$” to the code. But Ahk showed an error saying that “$+e” not recognized, i deleted it and used “$*e” now it works, thank you so much @Yane

Comment: @EvanElrod i was able to clean up the code, now it looks much cleaner and professional  thank you for the advice , will use it on my other script, been using this for all my hotkeys before, its really long 